# Tikz markers shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to know what's wrong when I change this code, which yields a red star, to a triangle shape:
This one works:

```
\pgfdeclareplotmark{mystar}{
    \node[star,star point ratio=2.25,minimum size=6pt,
    inner sep=0pt,draw=black,solid,fill=red] {};
}
```

This one, does not work:

```
\pgfdeclareplotmark{mystar}{
    \node[triangle,triangle point ratio=2.25,minimum size=6pt,
    inner sep=0pt,draw=black,solid,fill=yellow] {};
}
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: as fa as i know, triangle hasn't defined `point ratio` ... you should define it by defined options for triangles.

Comment: I've updated the OP

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
\addplot [
    mark=triangle*,
    mark options={fill=yellow},
    line width=0.7pt,
    black, 
    mark size=1.5pt,
]
```